# Are there any ancient myths about humans travelling back in time?

Tags: myth-identification

Does such a way of human time travel occur in ancient myths?

Comment: I'm not aware of any travelling back in time in ancient myths, but a fun innovation in modern mythology is the idea that UFOs are not aliens, but people from the future.

Comment: To add to what @Gibet said, it is the general consensus on SE that a good question shouldn't be deleted, especially if it already has a answer deemed good by the community. If OP really does not want this or another question under his name, it is possible to ask SE staff to disassociate it from his account: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96746/261831

Comment: Some possible examples here - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8496/time-travel-and-judaism

Answer (score 5):

I've been wracking my brain but can't think of any examples of ancient mythologies that involve travel *backwards* in time.

There are myths that involving travelling *forward* in time:

- In Jewish parables from the Talmud, the scholar [Honi ha-M'agel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honi_ha-M%27agel#Extended_sleep_story) falls asleep and wakes decades later.

These stories may be the basis for the popular modern folkloric tale of [Rip Van Winkle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rip_Van_Winkle), published in 1819 by Washington Irving.

- [Urashima Tarō](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urashima_Tar%C5%8D#Folktale_or_fairy_tale) is a Japanese folktale about a hero who travels to a magical undersea dragon palace. Although he only spends a few days there, when he returns to the real world, hundreds of years have passed.
- The Mahabharata includes the story of [Kakudmi/Raivata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakudmi), who visits Brahma in heaven, and, when he returns to the mundane world, finds that many ages have passed. (Brahma explained that time passes differently on differnt planes.)

In Celtic faerie lore, this same time distortion occurs in regard to [Tír na nÓg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%ADr_na_n%C3%93g), which probably derives from [Oisín](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ois%C3%ADn), son of [Finn Mac Cool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fionn_mac_Cumhaill), the first bard of Ireland:

- Oisín agrees to marry the fairy woman Niamh Goldenhair, and returns with her to the Land of Youth, where he becomes king.  Although he only stays for 3 days, when he returns to Ireland, 300 years have passed.

*(More recently, the celebrated contemporary author Gene Wolfe utilized this device in his [Wizard/Knight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wizard_Knight#Cosmology) books.)*

Comment: Hi. If I'm not wrong, I asked the question, but I'm from another account right now. Anyway, I found 2 legends (potentially of ancient origin or with ancient roots but I might be wrong), one from the 1600s and the other from Mohave folklore in these links: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journey_to_the_West#Sequels , en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohave_traditional_narratives . I hope I'm not wrong and that these stories are not later-date additions to the literature I talk about. You can check if they're surely not later additions, if you want, thank you.